# What should be the target architecture for only iPhones and scaled/zoom iPad app like instagram?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

Setting target architecture to **arm64 + armv7 + armv7s** is working for all iPhones, which is great for me. It is also running scaled/zoom in iPad Air; but it is running "fullscreen" in iPad Mini Retina. So what I need to do to make it run in all iPhones and all iPads in scaled/zoom screen?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess using [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) is a way to make only iphone app.

I set `camera-flash` requirement